# How to split a sparse matrix into two

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, correlation

I have a large sparse matrix which I need to correlate which haven't been possible for me because:

1. I cant convert the sparse matrix to a dense matrix due to R's memory limitation
2. I tried using packages `bigstats` and `bigmemory`, my R froze over (using a windows 10, 8GB laptop)
3. There's no correlation function in R's `Matrix` package

N.B: I am trying to correlate a sparse matrix in the format `'M'X + X'M - M'M'` which isn't possible which is why I am trying to split the sparse matrix into two or three, turn to dense matrix using `as.matrix()` then correlate using the `cor()` then combine the correlated results into one using `cbind()`

Now:

I want to ask if it's possible to split a sparse matrix into two or three parts, convert to dense matrices then correlate each dense matrix then cbind the two or three dense matrices into one then export to a text file.

What function can I use to split a sparse matrix into two or three bearing in mind that both the `i` and `p` parts of the sparse matrix are equal sizes with the same `dim`

```
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 7 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:73075722]  ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:73075722] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 500232 500232
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:73075722]  ...
  ..@ uplo    : chr "L"
  ..@ factors : list()
```

The correlation output will be in this format:

```
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  1.00000000 -0.8343860  0.3612926  0.09678096
[2,] -0.83438600  1.0000000 -0.8154071  0.24611830
[3,]  0.36129256 -0.8154071  1.0000000 -0.51801346
[4,]  0.09678096  0.2461183 -0.5180135  1.00000000
[5,]  0.67411584 -0.3560782 -0.1056124  0.60987601
[6,]  0.23071712 -0.4457467  0.5117711  0.21848068
[7,]  0.49200080 -0.4246502  0.2016633  0.46971736
           [,5]       [,6]       [,7]
[1,]  0.6741158  0.2307171  0.4920008
[2,] -0.3560782 -0.4457467 -0.4246502
[3,] -0.1056124  0.5117711  0.2016633
[4,]  0.6098760  0.2184807  0.4697174
[5,]  1.0000000  0.2007979  0.7198228
[6,]  0.2007979  1.0000000  0.6965899
[7,]  0.7198228  0.6965899  1.0000000
```

Comment: what are you correlating with what?  Can you give a *small* example that illustrates what you would want the output to be?

Comment: @BenBolker I have edited it to include an output. Thanks

Comment: If the correlation we're near 0, could it be rounded to 0?

Comment: @Cole Yes, it could be rounded to 0

Answer (score 1):

The `cor()` function is a way to efficiently calculate the `pearson` correlation between all of the columns. `cor` is very efficient but if we do not mind a hit in efficiency, we can calculate the `pearson` correlation manually:

```
n_row <- nrow(res)
cor_mat <- Matrix(0L,n_row, ncol(res))
cMeans <- Matrix::colMeans(res)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(res)-1)){
  x_delta = res[, i] - cMeans[i]
  sum_x_delta_sq = sum(x_delta^2)

  for (j in (i+1):nrow(res)){
    y_delta = res[, j] - cMeans[j]

    tmp <- sum(x_delta * y_delta) / sqrt((sum_x_delta_sq * sum(y_delta^2)))
    if (abs(tmp) > 0.05) cor_mat[i, j] <- tmp
  }
}
```

As sparsity of a matrix increases, we can make the above more complicated but more performant by separating operations involving non-sparse elements and operations involving sparse elements:

```
n_row <- nrow(res)

cor_mat <- Matrix(0L,n_row, ncol(res))
cMeans <- Matrix::colMeans(res)

for (i in 1){

  sp_i <- res[, i, drop = F]
  i_s <- sp_i@i + 1

  i_zero_delta = 0 - cMeans[i]
  i_non_zero_delta = sp_i@x - cMeans[i]

  sum_x_delta_sq = sum(c((n_row - length(i_s)) * i_zero_delta^2, i_non_zero_delta^2))

  for (j in (i+1):nrow(res)){

    sp_j <- res[, j, drop = F]
    j_s <- sp_j@i + 1

    j_zero_delta = 0L - cMeans[j]
    j_non_zero_delta = sp_j@x - cMeans[j]

    sum_y_delta_sq = sum(c((n_row - length(j_s)) * j_zero_delta^2, j_non_zero_delta^2))

    common <- intersect(i_s, j_s)
    only_i <- setdiff(i_s, j_s)
    only_j <- setdiff(j_s, i_s)
    none <- n_row - length(c(common, only_i, only_j))

    numerator = 0

    if (length(common) > 0) numerator = numerator + sum(i_non_zero_delta[match(common, i_s)] * j_non_zero_delta[match(common, j_s)])
    if (length(only_i) > 0) numerator = numerator + j_zero_delta * sum(i_non_zero_delta[match(only_i, i_s)])
    if (length(only_j) > 0) numerator = numerator + i_zero_delta * sum(j_non_zero_delta[match(only_j, j_s)])
    if (length(none) > 0)   numerator = numerator + i_zero_delta * j_zero_delta * none

    tmp <- numerator / sqrt(sum_x_delta_sq * sum_y_delta_sq)
    if (abs(tmp) > 0.05) cor_mat[i, j] <- tmp
  }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I implement dicing of a sparse_matrix by row indexing:

```
as.DF_spM <- function(data.use,chun_size="20000000",dg_class="dgCMatrix") {
    lapply(  split(seq(nrow(data.use)), (seq(nrow(data.use))-1) %/% as.numeric(chun_size) )  , function(nx) {
        switch(dg_class,
               dgTMatrix = {as(as.matrix(data.use[nx,]),"dgTMatrix")},
               dgCMatrix = {as(as.matrix(data.use[nx,]),"dgCMatrix")},
               dgRMatrix = {as(as.matrix(data.use[nx,]),"dgRMatrix")}
               )
        }) %>% Matrix.utils::rBind.fill()
}
```